# Login as user without password (For an Admin Use-Case.)

Tags: authentication, meteor

To check if the view of a user is working or to make change out of the users view point (in development) it can be quite useful to incarnate a certain user.

How would I do this with Meteor? Best would be a solution which is independent of the Account Authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To impersonate a user in production, you can call `setUserId` on the server, and `Meteor.connection.setUserId` on the client. For more details, see my [blog post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/impersonating-a-user).

Comment: If you are using Iron router and using `Meteor.user()` to check if the user is logged in on the waitOn function etc. Would this mean you have to place your subscriptions also in `Tracker.autorun`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()` to identify your person in your javascript you could use something like this to override it at the very top of your client js

```
Meteor.userId = function (impersonate_id) {
    return (impersonate_id) ? impersonate_id : Meteor.default_connection.userId();
}

Meteor.user = function (impersonate_id) {
    var userId = Meteor.userId(impersonate_id);
    if (!userId)
        return null;
    return Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
}
```

And now when you use `Meteor.userId` or `Meteor.user` modify your code so everywhere you use `Meteor.user` & `Meteor.userId` accepts an argument. So when you want to impersonate a user just pass it argument of the `_id` of the user you want to log in as

```
Meteor.user("1"); //Loads the data for user with _id 1
Meteor.user(); //Loads the actual logged in user
```

Also this will only work if you're actually the admin and your publish function allows you to see all your user's data

Comment: But how can you tell if impersonation is happening?  For example, how do I know when to pass in the impersonation_id?  Is there something on the connection object that contains impersonation state for example?